# How to open a .ico file in PHP?

Tags: php

I have tried to use php to caculate a image's avarage color.
So I use the php function: `imagecolorat()`, `imagecreatefromstring()`

This is a part of my code:

```
$fcontents = file_get_contents($imgname);
$im = @imagecreatefromstring($fcontents);
```

But I find it can read image successfully except .ico
How to deal with it?

Comment: Unless you can use ImageMagick, there is no built-in way to open an .ICO file in PHP as far as I know

Comment: I tried to used ImageMagick and it worked.But can it open a remote image?

Comment: you should be able to open any remote image file – as long as you know the path and the server side doesn't block such action

Comment: Then,why can I open a remove image by using imagecreatefrompng() but can't open the image by ImageMagick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function imagecreatefromstring() does not work with .ico - format: imagecreatefromstring() returns an image identifier representing the image obtained from the given image. These types will be automatically detected if your build of PHP supports them: JPEG, PNG, GIF, WBMP, and GD2.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/lordelph/icofileloader

```
$loader = new Elphin\IcoFileLoader\IcoFileService;
$im = $loader->extractIcon('/path/to/icon.ico', 32, 32);

//$im is a GD image resource, so we could, for example, save this as a PNG
imagepng($im, '/path/to/output.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is possible using this class

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2369-PHP-Extract-graphics-from-ico-files-into-PNG-images.html

Comment: This is from 2005 and doesn't support all types of .ico files. It's also GPL licenced. I contacted the author and brought it up to date and under an MIT licence here https://github.com/lordelph/icofileloader